# Multithreading Requests Python

Tags: python, multithreading

Is there a way to gradually open multiple new persistent connections to a host? I know that you can change the number of persistent connections using the code below, but how do you establish the connection?

```
s = requests.Session()
adapter = requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(pool_connections=5, pool_maxsize=28)
s.mount('https//', adapter)
```

I'm trying to get data off an API with the following rate limits:

- New Connections 2/s
- Requests 30/s

I'm multi-threading using **multiprocessing.pools.threadpools**, instead of multi-processing with **multiprocessing.pools** due to some Windows constraint.

**This is the function**:

```
def My_Func(PARAMS):
    ...
    req = requests.Request('GET', url, headers = headers, params = params)
    pre = req.prepare()
    resp = s.send(pre, stream = True, verify = False)
```

**And this is the code**:

```
s = requests.Session()

pool = ThreadPool(10)
Data = pool.map(My_Func, PARAMS)
pool.close()
pool.join()

s.close()
```

However, each thread that is spawned establishes a new connection (I think it's because the other connections have not been released back to the pool).This would mean that for a ThreadPool(10), I'll get some response 429 (exceed connection limit).

Answer (score 0):

from the [doc](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#keep-alive) :

> Note that connections are only released back to the pool for reuse once all body data has been read; be sure to either set stream to False or read the content property of the Response object.

`stream=True` does not release the connection